# C++ shared library with multiple classes

Tags: c++, qt, dll, namespaces, shared-libraries

I want have two or more classes inside a shared libary in Qt C++.
What is the way to make a shared library(dll) holding two or more classes?
Do they need to be nested inside a parent class or should I use namespaces?
What is the easiest or elegant method that you would direct me or give an example?

All classes are independent; and I only want to access proper class from the application. There may be many classes; so nested classes inside a single parent class would not be readable really. I thnik there is no partial class support in C++ . Also I am not sure if nested class and the namespaces are the only way to do that(?)

```
class A
{

public:
    A();
    void TestA();

};

class B
{

public:
    B();
    void TestB();

};
```

Application:

```
MyLib::A a;
MyLib::B b;
```

Here I have no idea how to implement MyLib.

Comment: Arrg! Everytime I exhausted to find a solution I wrote here; and few minutes later I find the solution. I find that I should export the class; i.e. class Q_DECL_EXPORT A

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested with the resolution is simply exporting the class

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT class A
{

public:
    A();
    void TestA();

};
```